# In Python: how to verify if file has been downloaded correctly before opening it

Tags: python

Is there a way to verify the file is valid before attempting to open it? The most simplistic way is to see if the file is 0 bytes in size. But I have encountered a situation when non-zero files are damaged/incomplete (mostly as a result of interrupted download). I wonder if there is some file header or other "common" place "inside" of every file where this information is recorded so it could be used to verify if the file is "completed" or it is 100% of what it is supposed to be...in term of data of course.

#### Edited later:

I am using urllib.urlretrieve(url_source, local_destination) to download the file. Is there a way to verify after download a destination file is the same file-size as the source?

Comment: If the information is inside the file, you will need to open the file to get that information.

Comment: What kind of file? Do you have a checksum?

Comment: What's to say a 500kb file is complete or incomplete?

Comment: _"I wonder if there is some file header or other "common" place "inside" of every file where this information is recorded"_. Nope. For instance, in a txt file, what you see in Notepad is exactly what the file contains. It could be 0 bytes long and still be "valid".

Comment: Are you asking how to tell if the file is open in another process? If so, that's going to be OS-specific. (e.g. `lsof` on linux, vs. catching an `IOError` on Windows)

Comment: It's completely file type specific.  You could write validators for various file types, but most if not all of them would require opening the file to read parts of it.

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/15157/34123

Comment: I am using `urllib.urlretrieve(url_source, local_destination)` to download the file. Is there a way to verify the destination file is the same file-size as the source?

Comment: So by "valid" you mean "same exact size"? If you really care about validity, you should be really careful here, since a corrupt file can have (easily) the same exact size (unless the corruption either removes the EOF or adds one inside the file).

Comment: The title has no relevance to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether a file is valid or not largely depends on what it means for the file to be valid. There is nothing that says a stream of random bytes is necessarily invalid without any sort of context. To ask "is this a valid file?" without any information should always result in "Maybe, who knows, can you provide more details?"

For example, one technique is to specify that the first n bytes of the file begins with a sequence of bytes, and then any readers would simply check the first n bytes.

There are many ways to check the validity of a file.

In your case, when you issue an HTTP request, the response may (or should) include the size of the content that you are requesting in a header called `content-length`. You can compare the size of the file that you download against the size that the response sent.

So for example:

```
data = urllib.urlretrieve(url, targetPath)
msg = data[1]
print(msg.getheader("content-length"))
```

Comment: Thanks! It would be great if some quick example of `content-length` in action would be posted!

Comment: Thanks MxyL! It is exactly what I've been looking for!

Comment: It doesn't tell you whether your file is "valid" or not but it's a quick way to determine whether you need to re-download or not.

Comment: I realized that! Thanks again!